# (Solved) Laravel New Installation - Removing PHP 7.1.23 from Mac without Brew

Tags: php, laravel, macos, composer-php

*Solution: I've updated my OS to the latest version where the latest PHP was supported.*

I've got a new laravel project
When I run `php artisan serve`
it shows:

```
MacBook-Pro% php artisan serve

Warning: require(/Users/username/Desktop/code/argon/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/username/Desktop/code/argon/artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/username/Desktop/code/argon/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /Users/username/Desktop/code/argon/artisan on line 18
```

`composer update` shows

```
MacBook-Pro% composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php ^7.2.5 but your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/tinker v2.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/tinker v2.1.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/tinker v2.0.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/tinker 2.x-dev requires php ^7.2 -> your PHP version (7.1.23) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[2.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.1.0, v2.2.0].



MacBook-Pro% php -v
PHP 7.1.23 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2018 18:20:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

also

```
MacBook-Pro% brew unlink php@7.1
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.1
MacBook-Pro% brew unlink php71
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php71
```

also

```
MacBook-Pro% which php
/usr/bin/php
```

Any ideas how to remove php 7.1.23 ?

Comment: You must have a very old macOS version. You can't remove the system version of PHP. Install a newer one.

Comment: It's MacOS Mojave v10.14.3

Answer (score 1):

php -v gives the following response:

```
WARNING: PHP is not recommended  
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.  
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
The release notes for Catalina contain the following remark:
```

[Info here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes)

> Scripting Language Runtimes Deprecations Scripting language runtimes
> such as Python, Ruby, and Perl are included in macOS for compatibility
> with legacy software. Future versions of macOS won’t include scripting
> language runtimes by default, and might require you to install
> additional packages. If your software depends on scripting languages,
> it’s recommended that you bundle the runtime within the app.

In short: macOS continues to include 'legacy' versions of things like Python, Ruby, Perl, and indeed PHP, so that existing code won't break, but Apple is leaving it to the user to install the versions that they want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution !

```
brew install php72
brew switch php@7.2 7.2.25
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead